# Trying to build Xerces-C++ for Android

Tags: android, c++, build, xml-parsing, xerces

I was looking for a way to build the Xerces-C++ library for Android that I need as a dependency of Delta3D game engine, but could not find any information on this. I would very much appreciate a professional advice.

Comment: Max, please tell what you have tried so far and what seems to be a problem. It might help people give you a better answer.

Comment: i have tried to generate the make file for it and made some minor changes on the code it self ( some missing includes due to unknown reasons 'well i guess its due to preprocessor definitions' and had some truble with some platform specific stuff, and now stuck with the XMLString class due to un-implemented functions on the android platform )

Comment: * forgot to say that i am using windows for all this, i know it doesn't matter cause the ndk should be the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy xercesc library with Android build scripts from [here](https://github.com/pelya/commandergenius/tree/sdl_android/project/jni/xerces).
Just copy it into your *jni* folder and run *ndk-build*.

Answer (score 2):

Most Android development is done in Java.  The Delta3D game engine is in C++, which means you'll need to start with the Android Native Development Kit (NDK).  The FAQ claims that the library uses cross-platform dependencies, so, in theory you should be able to use it on Android.  However, it is written for OpenGL, not OpenGL ES, which is the subset used in Android.  This could cause an issue.  The other concern would be memory footprint.  There is a fair amount of work that will probably need to be done to get this to compile under Android.  You might consider working with a library which has already been ported to Android (or written for it) rather than all the work that will be needed to port this, let alone writing your game.  Unless, you already have a game written in this game engine, which I understand why you would want to just port the library over.

Comment: thanks Paul for the quick reply ^_^, well as for the ndk , well xercesc has too many complication for a simple person like me would handle, as for GLES i guess ill just leave it to OSG to handle as Delta3D is built on top of it, ill just keep suffering in the build for now ^_^